# If $a \in A$, is it correct to say that $\{a\} \subset A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've read somewhere (an elementary text on naïve set theory or discrete mathematics) that if $a \in A$ then you can say either that $a \in A$ or, alternatively, that $\{a\} \subset A$. I think this is incorrect. I believe that the correct statement should be that $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$, the power set of $A$. Is there any set-theoretic (axiomatic, notational or whatever) justification for the said statement?

(Note added in proof: corrected $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$ for the former (typo) $\{a\} \subset 2^{A}$.)

Comment: This is just logic. Is every element of $\{a\}$ also an element of $A$? Is every element of $\{a\}$ also an element of $2^A$?

Comment: Implication $p\Rightarrow p \lor q$ is always true for every $p, q$ logical statements, despite their meaning.

Comment: The power set of $A$ is the set whose elements are all subsets of $A.$ Therefore $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$ is correct, not $\{a\} \subset 2^{A}.$

Comment: Definition of set *inclusion*: $X \subseteq A \text { iff  (for every x, if } x \in X \text { then } x \in A)$

Comment: An definition of *power set*: $X \in 2^A \text { iff } X \subseteq A$.

Comment: I've made a mistake in the statement of the problem: I wrote $\{a\} \subset 2^{A}$ instead of $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$. Corrected. Thanks to one responder for noticing that.

Comment: Can you give an example of $a$ and $A$ for which: $\{a\} \subset A$ is wrong while $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$ is correct?

Comment: On a second though I realized the source of my misunderstanding. The statement is clearly true.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \in A$, then $\{a\}$ is a singleton subset of $A$, because $A$ is a set which is nonempty as you are saying $a \in A$, so $\{a\} \subseteq A$, the proof is straightforward let $x \in \{a\}$, that is $x = a \implies x=a \in A$.
Now $2^{A}$ is the power set of $A$, that is set of all subsets of $A$, as $\{a\}$ is a subset of $A$, which follows that $\{a\} \in 2^{A}$. Interestingly, $\{a\}$ is a subset of $A$, but it is an element of $2^{A}$.